# Changing CSS onClick in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm changing(updating) css of a css class when i click on a certain div like follows.

**JS part**

```
constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            transform: 'rotateY(0deg)',
        };

        this.trait_select = this.trait_select.bind(this);

    }


    trait_select = (e) => {

        this.setState({

            transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'


        })

    }
```

**html part**

```
<div className="trait_box polaroid" onClick={this.trait_select}>
    <div className="main_trait_card" style={{transform: this.state.transform}}>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this piece of code work fine. But i want to change the css into `transform: 'rotateY(0deg)'` if the user clicks on `trait_select` again. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just change a little like:

```
trait_select = (e) => {
  const newTransform = this.state.transform == 'rotateY(180deg)' ? 'rotateY(0deg)' : 'rotateY(180deg)';
  this.setState({
    transform: newTransform
  })
}
```

It will toggle the value when `trail` is selected!

But I'd like to store transform enabled/disabled instead. So it would be:

**constructor**

```
this.state = { rotated: false };
```

**trait_select**

```
this.setState({ rotated: !this.state.rotated });
```

**html part**

```
<div className="trait_box polaroid" onClick={this.trait_select}>
    <div className="main_trait_card" style={{transform: this.state.rotated ? 'rotateY(180deg)' : 'none' }}/>
</div>
```

Comment: and 1 more thing. i have several divs with the same css classes used. When i used your solution every div starts to rotate. Is there anyway to apply the css only to the div that has been clicked?

Comment: You can extract that kind of div to a Component to store its rotate status